# Is there a way to initialise array of integers with string?

Tags: c

Suppose that we have

```
int arr[3]; 
char str[20] = "{10,20,30}";
```

Is it possible to initialise arr with str?

Comment: You will need to write code that will extract numbers from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not statically, you would need to parse the string and then assign the parsed values to `arr`.

You can parse numbers (and more) from strings with `sscanf` or with `strtol` (just parsing integers).

One way to parse `{10,20,30}` could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[3] = {0};
    int pos = 0;

    char str[20] = "{10,20,30}"; 

    // str + 1: skip the first character '{'
    char *token = strtok(str + 1, ",");

    while (token) {
        int tmp = 0;

        // check if the parsing was actually successful
        if (sscanf(token, "%d", &tmp) == 1) {
            // a good program would check if 'pos' is within 
            // proper range of 'arr', in the case of arr[3]: 
            // acceptable range: 0-2
            arr[pos] = tmp;

            ++pos;
        }

        // get the next token
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(* arr); ++i) {
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

This is *very* rudimentary it lacks proper handling of the `{}` braces and `strtok` IS NOT able to process more than one string at a time. A better solution would use `strtok_r`.

Comment: Not to mention the caveat about consecutive commas.

Comment: `strtok( ..., "{}, " )`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that specifically, statically, but you can kind of do the reverse.

You can create a "to string" macro like this:

```
#define __STR(x) #x
#define STR(x) __STR(x)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
#define NUMS {10,20,30}
int arr[3] = NUMS;
char str[] = STR(NUMS);
```